# merge data frame and named vector

Tags: r, vector, merge

I have a data frame and a name vector:

```
df=data.frame(col1=letters[1:3],col2=rnorm(3))
v=c(a=2,b=4,c=56,d=65)
```

I want to merge them, and keep only the values from the data frame

```
v=data.frame(v)
merge(df,v,by.x='col1',by.y=row.names,all.x=TRUE)
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

I want:

```
  col1   rnorm.3.  v
1    a  0.6182781  2
2    b  0.9559001  4
3    c -0.5459661 56
```

Note my real data is 1M rows and 1.5M named vector

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can `match` the `col1` with `names` of `v`

```
df$v <- v[match(df$col1, names(v))]
df

#  col1       col2  v
#1    a  0.6658478  2
#2    b -1.6029447  4
#3    c  0.9019324 56
```

---

A more simple approach by @Frank in comments ,

```
df$v <- v[df$col1]
```

Answer (score 10):

We can create a column with the `names` of the vector and do the `merge`

```
merge(df, data.frame(v, col1 = names(v)), all.x = TRUE)
#   col1        col2  v
#1    a -1.61035092  2
#2    b -0.04848256  4
#3    c  2.74926847 56
```

In the OP's code, the `row.names` in the `by.y` should be in quotes

```
merge(df, data.frame(v), by.x = "col1", by.y = "row.names")
#  col1        col2  v
#1    a -1.61035092  2
#2    b -0.04848256  4
#3    c  2.74926847 56
```

---

Or use `left_join` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
left_join(df, data.frame(v, col1 = names(v)))
```

Comment: Or with data.table `setDT(df); df[stack(v), on=.(col1=ind), v := i.values][]`